# CodeIgniter directory problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, path

In my CodeIgniter project, I am trying to do something very simple. I'm coding a stylesheet into my view. The problem comes when the stylesheet is in a different folder under the *application* folder called *assets*. When I try coding something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/assets/stylesheet.css">
```

or even:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ProjectName/application/assets/stylesheet.css">
```

I don't get any result. I've tried every trick with the `href` attribute, and I've double-checked my directory so I know I've got it right.

My base url is `http://localhost/ProjectName/` + I've enabled the *URL helper*, so I know that isn't the problem.

The only thing I could think it would be is the .htaccess files.  When I view my source, and try to view the independent css file in the browser I get a message like:

> You don't have permission to access /ProjectName/application/assets/... on this server.

Could this be my problem, and could you please help me fix this?

Comment: on the path specified :http://localhost/ProjectName/application/assets/stylesheet.css , are you able to see your css file? try clicking on css file from page source in browser to see where exactly it is pointing in your browser.

Comment: I just added something to the question which I think answers your question, @akshayb

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered bad practice to put CSS and similar assets in CodeIgniter's *application* folder. It's recommended that one should keep their *application* and *system* folders above the web root.

The default `.htaccess` in the *application* directory will `Deny from all`. You could change this to allow access and you should be able to access your CSS as you are currently attempting, but I wouldn't recommend it. You should keep your assets at the application's root, similar to this:

```
– public_html
    – index.php
    - assets
        - stylesheet.css
...
```

Then link to the CSS, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(assets/stylesheet.css); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this........

```
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
             @import url("/project_name/application/assets/style.css");
    </style>
```

Comment: what view renders if pure HTML, how come @import make any difference? Just a curiosity?

Comment: there is no much difference you can search what is the difference between import and link in css. Import is not good but it's working for me and i though give a try using this also......

Answer (score 0):

If the message is 'you don't have permission, try :

```
<Directory "absolute/path/to/assets/folder/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You need to restart apache server as well. On ubuntu, you can do it:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put those assets outside the application folder. Only then you can access it via base_url();

Create a folder outside application folder called assets and inside that create another folder called css and then put all your css inside there. Then Change the base_url() to your path. for ex. http:/localhost/project path. This will access your project path.

Then in ur css line do this